# Java: converting numbers and string to hex returns different results. Why?

Tags: java, hex, ascii, primitive, primitive-types

Trying to convert numbers to hex got me stuck, take a look:

Number: 32

Hex expected (ASCII): 20

Result from number that came as string:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%02x", new BigInteger(1, "32".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII))));
```

Gives me 33 32 as result (which I understood that happens because it parses 3 (=33) and 2 (=32) )

Result converting as number:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(32));
```

Gives me 20 (correct)

I would like to better understand this situation, can someone explain what differs from each other? (please don't say "because it calls different methods... be friendly)

Also, the first approach lets me set the Charset and the second one doesn't. Why?

Comment: It sounds like you understand the difference: "32" gives you the ASCII for '3', then the ASCII for '2'.  32 on its own gives a different value.  It sounds like you understand it already.

Comment: Yes, but if ASCII does not have 32 number in table, how toHexString() knows to convert it? And what about Charset? I feel I did not understood everything...

Comment: `Integer.toHexString(32)` has nothing whatsoever to do with ASCII.  It just converts the number 32 into hexadecimal.  `"32".getBytes(US_ASCII)` uses the ASCII table to convert `3` into a byte, then `2` into a byte.

Comment: So you are saying ASCII is only valid to convert Strings? ASCII does not apply to numbers? I still not understanding LOL

Comment: Yes.  That is exactly the point.  ASCII is a way that strings get turned into numbers.

Comment: @LouisWasserman please add a complete answer in this question (and if possible explaining this point of only strings uses ASCII) so then I can mark it as the correct aswer.

Answer (score 2):

return of `getBytes()` method from a String, separates every byte of that String which in your case would be '3' and '2'.

printing them using `String.format("%02x", .....`, shows hexadecimal number of their ASCII codes.

in the other hand, `Integer.toHexString(32)` gets data from `toHexString` method and this method does not separate every single byte and gets data in hexadecimal format.

Comment: But I still confused about the Charset, how Integer.toHexString(32) know which Charset should be used? What if I need another Charset?